# Allow Facebook access only in specific hours of the day with squid

Tags: squid, time, webfilter

I've been able to install squid on my Ubuntu Server with basic authentication and everything works perfectly.
Recently the boss asked to block facebook access and I did it with no problems.
Now it looks that he wants to give the users possibility to access during lunchtime...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Taken from my configfile:

```
# When is Facebook allowed?
acl allowfacebooktime time MTWHF 12:15-13:45
# Facebook ACL
acl facebookdotcom  dstdomain .facebook.com
# Only allow Facebook as described by allowfacebooktime
http_access allow facebookdotcom allowfacebooktime
# Else block facebook
http_access deny facebookdotcom
```

Answer (score 6):

Squid supports time-base ACLS

Something like this should work:

```
acl FACEBOOK dst www.facebook.com
acl LUNCH time MTWHF 12:30-1:30

http_access allow FACEBOOK LUNCH
http_access deny FACEBOOK
```

The "FACEBOOK" acl is probably wrong, I'm just making this up as I go :). The above says to allow access to whatever matches the FACEBOOK acl, during the time period matched by the LUNCH acl. It then says to deny access to the FACEBOOK acl as a fall back. Rules are matched in order, so the lunchtime rule has priority.

Squid Wiki page on [time ACLS](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#How_can_I_allow_some_clients_to_use_the_cache_at_specific_times.3F)

Answer (score 1):

Hello friends my boss called and ordered me deny face facebook in working hours and allowed only in morning 08:00-09:00 so used this acl and apply

```
acl facebooktime time MTWHF 09:00-10:00
acl FBDomain  dstdomain .facebook.com
http_access allow FBDomain facebooktime
http_access deny  FBDomain
```

This works properly..

Comment: Uhhh, your times don't quite match and what does your answer add to the accepted answer?